# Error while using the seacorenlp package in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nlp, modulenotfounderror

I am working on a NLP project and planning to use the [seacorenlp package](https://pypi.org/project/seacorenlp/) for POS tagging.

However, when I tried the code as explained on the website:

```
!pip install seacorenlp
from seacorenlp.tagging import POSTagger

th_text = 'ผมอยากกินข้าว'

# Native Models
native_tagger = POSTagger.from_pretrained('pos-th-ud-xlmr')
native_tagger.predict(th_text)
```

It gave me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from seacorenlp.tagging import POSTagger
      3 th_text = 'ผมอยากกินข้าว'
      5 # Native Models

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seacorenlp'
```

Can you help me troubleshoot the "ModuleNotFoundError" related to the missing 'seacorenlp' module in my NLP project?